# How to access own localhost on Google Cloud Platform from other devices

Tags: windows, server, google-cloud-platform

I had a Windows server on GCP. I am running an app on localhost:8080. However, I want to access the localhost from other devices (maybe on a different network connection). What should I do?

Comment: You can use something like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access localhost from outside the machine. Localhost is an internal network address. This is often called a loopback address.

Depending on what software you are running, usually you can change the "bind" address from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1 to` 0.0.0.0`. The later means all available networks.

Note: 127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost.

Comment: Is there any way to reroute traffic from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 if I can't make my software directly listen all available networks (0.0.0.0)?

Comment: @MAxShvedov Look into a product like Nginx to reverse proxy localhost: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ If you have more questions, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of the answer from John, you need to ensure the following items are in place correctly:

1. The server listens to request from a remote network (0.0.0.0 is an easy step, e.g. using npm)
2. Create a Firewall rule for port 8080, you can define which IP can access this port number
3. Assign a Public IP of this VM to send requests to the service http://${public_ip}:8080/, because you need different network access